# How to search for a file from Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to search for a file from Eclipse plugin.
I used the following code but it did not work.

```java
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please enter the search file name");
    for (IProject project : root.getProjects()) {
        IFile file = project.getFile(str);
        if (file.exists()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, file.getName());
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found! ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you expecting just the name of the file (e.g. fred.txt) and then looking throughout your workspace for that file?

Comment: yes, just the file name e.g. "SalesHandler.java"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the file name you can write a recursive method that searches containers for files and more containers.  Start with the workspace root.  Some things to note:

- IWorkspaceRoot, IProject and IFolder are all IContainers.
- IWorkspaceRoot contains IProjects
- IProjects and IFolders contain IFolders and IFiles
- IContainers have a members() method that returns a list of the IFiles and IContainers contained directly in that container.
- IWorkspaceRoot, IProjects, IFolders, IFiles are all IResources and IResource has a method that tells you what kind of resource it is (project, folder, file, etc.)
- An IFile can tell you its file name, project, project relative path and absolute file name

Comment: Thanks so much , it works 
The problem was I could not find the organized information of the structure of the project you provided :)
Is there a way to highlight the found file? i.e. make it selected